# OFFSET in LINQ to SQL

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I am using EF 6.0.0 in C# ASP.net MVC 4.
When I use Take(10) and Skip(30) in linq, in sql profiler I can see it as TOP 10 and  "> 30" in where clause.
How to write linq such that I get

```
OFFSET 30 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Thanks.

Comment: So is it not possible in EF 6.0.0?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to do something like this?

```
int skipRecords = 30;
int takeRecords = 10;
context.SomeEntities.Skip(() => skipRecords)
    .Take(() => takeRecords)
    .ToList();
```

If you use variables, sql query will be parameterized.